# "Add"-Button when editing Your Communities is misplaced

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, firefox, communities-list

Just updated to new FireFox 29 and I noticed an Issue when editing the Your Communities section. The "Add"-Button is placed on a new line below the TextBox.

Other Browser like Chrome and IE have no issues. Zoom-Level is set to 100%.

[image]

Comment: Repro on even on FF v28

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox `43.0.3`

Answer (score 2):

The "Add" button is now properly aligned in the Firefox browser.

I have verified the alignment issue in the Firefox `50.1.0`.

The recent screenshot in Firefox for your reference:

[image: Add button aligned properly in Firefox]