# Colors of code-formatted text in comment help is difficult to read

Tags: bug, design, comments, code-formatting

The new color scheme on the collapsible help section when adding a comment is very difficult to read for the highlighted sections. The new darker highlight does not have enough contrast with the black text. (This would contrast well if the text was white instead.)

[image: Screenshot of comment help]

Comment: This issue has been previously reported and acknowledged [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394150/335251) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394894/335251), and also [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394997/335251) for dark mode.

Comment: But apparently not fixed. Yet ._.

Comment: @V2Blast a month and a half ago. They're looking for feedback on a new solution, sure, but regressive changes should be reverted immediately while a new solution is worked on, not left in place making life difficult for users.

Comment: @Andrew: Don't complain to me about it, I don't work there anymore :P I just wanted to link back to where it's been previously reported/acknowledged, so folks can follow along.

Comment: It is kind of surprising given the (seeming) amount of forethought that went into state-of-the-art UI color design https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390761/colors-update-a-more-detailed-look?rq=1 I wonder if they thought it was okay as it was, which is difficult to believe, or they somehow didn't check it? That shade of blue is one of my favorite colors so I don't mind *THAT* much but it would be very difficult to read for anyone with accessibility (vision) challenges.

Comment: @EllieKesselman The problem is everywhere in those examples they use the darker blue background for text they have white text, they didn't enforce that properly in practice though

Comment: @Andrew wow you are amazingly fast! I was too shy to ask about it for a few weeks, and [when I finally did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395732/why-is-the-color-contrast-in-the-comment-instructions-barely-readable), there were at least **four** people who had already asked the **EXACT** same question. (I'm embarrassed because I know better than to do that!) On Meta, it is usually (or used to be) quite nuanced, what is considered duplicate or not.

Comment: @Andrew Hmm, interesting that they chose black text on a white background for those parts of the help. (Not sure that would be so great either; whatever SE used to use was perfectly readable.) You're correct: They should have reverted immediately. That is a good heuristic, because it avoids the scenario of something else coming up unexpectedly, and the UI horror "making life difficult for users" for ages.... "ages" being at least two months now!

Comment: @EllieKesselman I'm betting they didn't 'choose' anything, my guess is they just modified the color code variables for the backgrounds without consideration for where it was used, and since that text was set to (or defaulted to) black, when they made the change to the definition for that shade of blue it caused the issue. Hanlon's Razor.