# Why is the color contrast in the comment instructions barely readable?

Tags: feature-request, design, comments

This is an example from the *[Politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour)* site. I have noticed it on other beta sites. Black font letters on a medium-dark blue background is difficult to read.

I am sorry about the large section that is greyed out. That was my doing.

[image: Comment screen]