# The "Add" button on the "A list of all 183 Stack Exchange Sites" menu is not visible until you hover over it

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

The "Add" and "Reset" buttons on the "A list of all 183 Stack Exchange Sites" menu are not visible until you hover over them.

To replicate this bug:

1. Click on the "A list of all 183 Stack Exchange Sites" menu in the top right of the top navigation bar

[image: YOUR COMMUNITIES menu with edit button]

2. Click on "edit" to the right of "YOUR COMMUNITIES"
3. Type a site into the edit box, for example: "Engineering"

[image: Typing Engineering into edit box]

And now what?

Clicking ENTER or RETURN does nothing.

There does not seem to be any buttons to press.

There are two ways to proceed.

1. **Either** press TAB and the focus moves to the "Add" button which appears next to the edit box
2. **Or** move the mouse around until it hovers over the "Add" button which appears next to the edit box

[image: the add button appears]

It is now possible to click the "Add" button and then press the "Save" button below to save your new list of "YOUR COMMUNITIES"

[image: the reset button appears]

Similarly, the "Reset" button is not visible until you mouse over it or you TAB to it.

I first noticed this bug on Chrome on an Android phone on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), and I only finally saw the location of the "Add" button when I tested it on the same Android phone on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) in Stack Overflow's Dark Mode.

On a Windows PC, on zooming the relevant area on Meta, it is just possible to make out the word "Add" where the button is:

[image: zoom on invisible Add button]

Comment: I reported this on October 26 by posting an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394227/289691) to [New colors launched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/393939/289691)

Comment: @Rubén Yes, I see. I noticed this on Android (which I don't normally use for [SE](https://stackexchange.com/)) when I was trying to find an easier way to switch between sites. I also noticed that it was not possible to sort the sites on Android by dragging the sites up and down. I am not sure if sorting is impossible on all smartphones or just mine as I have not tested that exhaustively.

Comment: I noticed the same drag-and-drop problem on my Android device (Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro, Chrome, normal, and beta).

Comment: duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394268/997587 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394227/997587, being tracked by internal ticket "ref 475"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was an issue related to the [new colors launched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394268/888623). The top navigation bar of SE uses the dark mode color classes as the default. The SE dropdown buttons were inheriting those classes even though it had a light background. We've now restored the proper color overrides needed for those buttons and the issue is resolved.