# The "Add" button in the edit interface for "Your Communities" is nearly invisible

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, user-experience

I was trying to add my most visited sites from the top-right dropdown menu, and it took me so long, because I did not realize the faint add button is not disabled.

I thought I was doing something wrong and the button would become active (more prominent) if I do it right. It took so long to figure out that's the button's default state. Could this issue be fixed? It's basic UX.

[image]

Comment: duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394268/997587 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394227/997587, being tracked by internal ticket "ref 475"

Comment: Thanks. Can merge if required.

Comment: Re *"It's basic UX"*: Yes, but it is [a thing of the past](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/) (unfortunately).

Comment: We don't merge duplicates here,  just closing one as a duplicate of the other, this way it's easier to find and still leaving signposts around. (e.g. more keywords.)